# How can i convert puppeteer Array.from().map() from C# to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, puppeteer-sharp

I am using this code in C# and it is working properly.

```cs
using PuppeteerSharp;

var links = page.EvaluateExpressionAsync<string[]>
            ("Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a span'))
            .map(a => a.textContent);").Result;
```

But when i tried to convert JavaScript using this code, it is not working.

```js
const puppeteerChrome = require('puppeteer');

const links = await page.evaluate(() => 
                    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a span'))
                   .map(a => a.textContent));
```

How can i solve this problem.

Comment: And _"it's not working"_ means what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem like this.

```js
const links = await page.evaluate(() =>
              Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a span'), e => 
              e.textContent));
```